# Scriptural reference for the fact that Prabhu is fully present in His Name itself. He has put all His powers in His Name

Tags: scripture, practice, book-recommendation

On Internet, I came across this text today(highlighted portion).

[image]

In case the picture is not loading, here is the text which is written in the image

> The Vedas declare that God is fully present in His Name itself. He has
> put all His powers in His Name. So, He is present in the same form in
> His Name as He is in Vrindavan!

Can someone kindly provide some scriptural references? I would be thankful.

Comment: Do you want an answer from Vedas only?

Answer (score 3):

Sri Krishna says in the *Gita* chapter 10 verse 25 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> Of the great rishis I am Bhrigu, and of words I am the monosyllable "Om." Of sacrifices I am the sacrifice of japa; of immovable things I am the Himalaya.

The *Katha Upanishad* I.ii.15-17 says (Swami Gambhirananda translator):

> 15. I tell you briefly of that goal which all the Vedas with one voice propound, which all the austerities speak of, and wishing for which people practice Brahmacharya. It is this, viz *Om*.
> 16. This letter (Om), indeed, is the (inferior) Brahman (Hiranyagarbha); and this letter is, indeed, the supreme Brahman. Anybody, who, (while) meditating on this letter, wants any of the two, to him comes that.
> 17. This medium is the best; this medium is the supreme (and the inferior) Brahman. Meditating on this medium, one becomes adorable in the world of Brahman.

And Patanjali says in his *Yoga Sutras* I.27-28 (Swami Vivekananda translator):

> 27. His manifesting word is Om.
> 28. The repetition of this (Om) and meditating on the meaning (is the way).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is very obvious that the sentence is from an ISKCON website. The language and wording is so typical of them.

If you're looking for scriptural references for those words exactly, you may not find any.

But there are equivalent statements praising the name as a way of meditating on the deity.

Examples:

Rig Veda 10.5.2c:

> ऋतस्य पदं कवयो नि पान्ति गुहा नामानि दधिरे पराणि 
> The sages protect the state of the Truth, they carry the highest secret names.

Rig Veda 4.58.2a:

> वयं नाम प्र ब्रवामा घृतस्यास्मिन्यज्ञे धारयामा नमोभिः 
> We say the name of the Ghrtam, we worship (or meditate on) it with obeisances.

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu Shashranama Bhisma Uvaccha 19th sloka

yāni nāmāni gauṇāni vikhyātāni mahātmanaḥ |
ṛṣibhiḥ parigītāni tāni vakṣyāmi bhūtaye || 19 ||

Those famous names of the Great Soul which bring out His manifold qualities celebrated by rishs (seers) I shall declare for the good (of all).

with the above we infer that Names describes Gods qualities or Gunas. Now Chandyogya upanishad says

Lords Guna and Swarroopa(form of Lord)are not different.

With this we can say for sure that Lords Name -> Lords Guna -> Swaroopa of Lord

Lords Name = Lord himself By logic one can infer from the above.

Sanatkumara reply to Narada

Sa yo nama brahmeti upaste yavan-namno gatam, tatrasya yatha kamacaro bhavati yo nama brahmetyupaste’sti, bhagavah, namno bhuya iti; namno vava bhuyo’stiti, tan-me bhagavan bravitviti.

Whoever   contemplates   ‘name’   as   Brahman,   which   means  to  say,  whoever  regards  the  object  of  meditation  as  absolute,  gains  whatever  that  object  includes  within  its  gamut.  The  principle  of  meditation  is  this:  whatever  the  object  of  your  meditation  be,  that  has  to  be  taken  as  absolute.   There   should   not   be   anything   external   to   it,   because  if  the  mind  conceives  something  higher  than  that  particular object, then that higher thing becomes the object of  meditation.  The  point  is  that  the  object  that  you  have  chosen  for  your  meditation  should  be  the  last  point  of  the  reach  of  your  mind,  beyond  which  it  cannot  go.  Then  it  becomes  the  absolute.  So  this  absolute  is  only  a  name  that  we give to the best possible reach of the mind in any level or degree   of   experience.   ‘Name   is   Brahman’—this   means   name  is  the  absolute,  inasmuch  as  we  are  in  a  realm  of  names  only.  Why  should  we  not  take  the  higher  degree  as  the absolute, and not the lower one? Because the higher one cannot  be  the  content  of  the  mind  in  its  present  state.  Suppose we are asked to meditate on the heavenly regions. We  cannot,  because  we  do  not  know  what  it  means.  The  heavenly regions are beyond the reach of the mind. We will only  superimpose  physical  pictures  of  our  imagination  on  paradise, Brahma-loka,  etc.  This  is  not  what  is  intended.  We  must  limit  ourselves  to  the  extent  of  our  knowledge,  and   complete   the   meditation   regarding   that   particular   object  as  absolute  in  itself.  So,  Narada  was  asked  to  take  ‘name’  as  the  absolute.  The  result  of  this  meditation  on  name is  that  to  the  extent  name  goes—to  the  extent  of  the  reach   of   the   mind   theoretically,   conceptually—to   that   extent, the meditator will be free.

chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/chhand/Chhandogya_Upanishad.pdf